# Error while importing LDIF file in Apache Directory Studio

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldif, apache-directory

I'm connected to my LDAP connection.
I'm trying to import an LDIF file to it by right clicking and using the wizard.
As I choose the file, check the overwrite option and press OK,
I get the following error:

```
Error while importing LDIF
javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: 
    at org.apache.directory.studio.connection.core.io.api.DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.checkResponse(DirectoryApiConnectionWrapper.java:1359)
```

And this appears in the Modification Logs tab:

```
#!RESULT ERROR
#!CONNECTION ldap://192.168.99.100:389
#!DATE 2018-01-24T11:01:17.743
#!ERROR
dn: dc=mycompany,dc=net
changetype: add
dc: mycompany
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
o: mycompany.net
```

I tried googling around with the error but can't find anything on this particular matter.

Also, as I choose the LDIF-file, even after uninstalling and reinstalling the program, it warns already upon selecting the LDIF-file that "selected logfile already exists".

Answer (score 0):

The description of [javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/naming/NameAlreadyBoundException.html) sounds like this is a weird name for the LDAP result code *entryAlreadyExists(68)* returned when processing the [LDAP Add Operation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511#section-4.7).

It means just that: An LDAP entry with this DN already exists. You cannot add a second one with the same DN.